# How to provide comparison function in std::set for unique element insertion?

Tags: c++, stl, set, operator-overloading

I have following user defined class,

```
class simple
{
public:
  simple(string str1, string str2)
   : s1(str1)
   , s2(str2)
  {
  }
  const string& getS1() const {return s1;}
  const string& getS2()const {return s2;} 
  bool operator<(const simple& s) {
    return strcmp(this->getS1().c_str(), s.getS1().c_str()) < 0 && strcmp(this->getS2().c_str(), s.getS2().c_str()) < 0;
  }
private:
  const string s1;
  const string s2;
}
```

And I'm storing this  class in a std::set as below:

```
std::set<simple*> mySimplePtrSet;
simple* s1 = new simple("stack", "overflow");
simple* s2 = new simple("go", "ogle");
simple* s3 = new simple("stack", "overflow");
simple* s4 = new simple("go", "good");
simple* s5 = new simple("my", "overflow");
```

In above example set should only contains s1, s2, s4 and s5.

How to store unique class objects in set considering bothe the data members of class (i.e. s1 and s2)?

I tried with following compartor function but it's not working.

```
struct myCom {
   bool operator()(const simple* a,const simple* b){
      return *a < *b;
   }
};
```

**NOTE:** Sorting is not important in my case, if the elements inserted unsorted is fine for me.

Comment: Why are you using pointers?

Comment: Interesting `operator<`. It's not even using the provided argument.

Comment: Clarifying the above comment:  the code compares `this` to `this` when the obvious intent was to compare `this` to `s`

Comment: A more complicated question is what is meant by "unique" and how the two parts of the comparison are meant to interact.  The usual way is for the second to act as a tie breaker for the first.  That was **NOT** done in the provided rules.  Other ways of mixing the two comparisons could create a valid ordering, but the quoted one (after fixing the bug mentioned above) would not.

Comment: @All, first thingis : I have special requirement of storing the class pointer only.
Second thing is : "Unique" means both data members of one object matchs with other object's data members. 
i.e. obj1.s1 == obj2.s1 and obj1.s2 == obj2.s2

Comment: Given that definition of unique, you need to rewrite the comparison the usual way so that the second part is involved only when the the first parts are equal.  Brahim quoted the exact rule under which your ordering is not valid.  But even if it were valid it is not what you needed.  You needed the common tie breaker pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You're storing pointers so the comparator is simply comparing the memory addresses, not your custom `operator<`.

Stop using `new` and store the actual objects in the map:

```
std::set<simple> mySimpleSet;
mySimpleSet.emplace("stack", "overflow");
mySimpleSet.emplace("go", "ogle");
mySimpleSet.emplace("stack", "overflow");
mySimpleSet.emplace("go", "good");
mySimpleSet.emplace("my", "overflow");
```

Or if you *really* need to store pointers then you have to provide a custom comparator that doesn't compare the memory addresses but the objects at those memory addresses.

Also your `operator<` is flawed. You're using `std::string` so use `std::string::compare` instead of `strcmp`, and you're not using the parameter `s`. Something like this would work better:

```
bool operator<(const simple& s) {
  return getS1() < s.getS1() && getS2() < s.getS2();
}
```

Comment: The standard requires that the compare operation has to be a strict weak ordering. I am not sure it is the case. [transitivity of incomparability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_ordering#Strict_weak_orderings) doen not hold I think

Comment: instead of using `compare()` you can just use the `operator<` of `std::string`

Comment: @NathanOliver, since the requirement was to use the second string only as a tie breaker for the first, `std::string::operator<` is not the right way to do the first comparison.  It only looked like it could be right because another bug was not fixed first.

Comment: Could you please add solution with usage of class pointer for this?

Comment: @JSF That may be but `getS1().compare(s.getS1()) < 0` is the same as `getS1() < s.getS1()` and that is what I was pointing out.

Comment: `std::tie(s1, s2) < std::tie(s.s1, s.s2)`

Comment: Using `std::tie` is more readable.  Calling `compare` once (for s1 vs. s.s1) but using its result twice is more efficient.  `(c=s1.compare(s.s1))<0 || c==0 && s2<s.s2`